# How to rewrite select statement if it contains function?

Tags: sql-server, performance, function, optimization, conditional-statements

After all my optimization i found that stored takes huge time for this select statement because it contains function in select and where condition . please help me to re-write the select statement.

```
if OBJECT_ID('QATR_TestCase0003_ElementElIDContainsUpperCase')         
is not null drop table QATR_TestCase0003_ElementElIDContainsUpperCase        
select elid, tsmkey, dbo.[ContainCapLetter](elid) ContaintCap ,  
cast('Element elid  '+elid+' contains UPPER CASE in GenProductsAll ' as 
nvarchar(255)) datastatus         
into QATR_TestCase0003_ElementElIDContainsUpperCase from TblGenProductsAll        
where dbo.[ContainCapLetter](elid) <>0
```

below is my function which i wrote :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ContainCapLetter] (@str1 as nvarchar(255))    
RETURNS int  
BEGIN   
declare @j int,  @i int
set @i=0  
 select @j = len(@str1)  

while @j >0  
begin  
If unicode(left(@str1,1)) not between 64 and 91  
begin  
set @str1 = right(@str1,len(@str1)-1)  
select @j= len(@str1)  
end  

Else If unicode(left(@str1,1)) between 64 and 91  
begin  
set @i= 1  
set @j= 0  
end  

end  
return @i  
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this.

```
select elid, tsmkey, 
    CASE WHEN elid like '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ContaintCap ,
    cast('Element elid  '+elid+' contains UPPER CASE in GenProductsAll ' as nvarchar(255)) datastatus         
into QATR_TestCase0003_ElementElIDContainsUpperCase 
from TblGenProductsAll        
where 
    elid like '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Comment: why A-z in like condition . please may i know

Comment: He's finding upper case characters in a case sensitive collation, therefore excludes [a-z].

Comment: it checks the column contains any uppercase chars

Comment: @SerkanArslan Thank you . is it possible to replace function in select staement